# Java — Is it OK to discard Future return values?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

If an async method returns a `Future` object, but we don't care whether the underlying operation succeeds or fails, are there any adverse effects from calling the method and not storing the returned `Future`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends if you care whether the operation has been executed or cancelled.

Comment: I don't. I just want to call the method and forget about it, so to speak.

Comment: If you don't care the returned value, why did not use Runnable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you also don't care whether the operation has been executed or cancelled, then yes, you can ignore the returned Future.